# how to put in mathematical equation in C

Tags: c, math, equation

I've been trying to look up on Google how to put in an equation in my program but wasn't able to find any. How do you include:

```
x = ( -b + √b2 - 4ac ) / 2a
```

in the program?

Here's my code:

```
{
    int a, b, c;
    float x;

    //statements
    printf("Enter three integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

    //computeforX

    x = ( -b + √b2 - 4ac ) / 2a  

    printf("The value of x is %.1f", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What programming language are you talking about here?

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate the equation or are you simply trying to display the equation? This looks like one of the C languages like C++, is that correct?

Comment: this isn't correct or good practice.  what if a is zero?  b?  c?  There are special cases to account for.

Comment: Also, are we to assume the second portion of the equation is `the square root of b then multiplied by 2` or is it `the square root of the result of b multiplied by 2`?

Comment: @Thomas: I would infer that this is supposed to be the equation for solving a quadratic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Quadratic_formula.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - Agreed which means the formula as presented is way off.

Comment: hi guys, i'm doing the C programming. Sorry forgot the important part..

Comment: in answering @Thomas question, it is square root of b squared minus 4ac

Comment: I've never seen anyone use Unicode characters as operators in a ASCII-based language.

Comment: @muntoo, hi, that's why I was asking for help how to write it correctly in the editor

Comment: @redkimono Just a tip: If you can't see it on your keyboard, it probably isn't an operator. (You *can* use Unicode characters in strings `std::cout << "√144 = 12";`, but only if your IDE has Unicode support enabled. [Or something like that.])

Comment: This is a formula, rather than an equation. You either need a different language for equations, such as Modelica, or to implement a suitable algorithm for balancing or solving the equation for your domain.

Comment: note that the expression is incorrect. It should be `x = ( -b + √(b2 - 4ac) ) / 2a`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming we're talking about C (or C++) here, you will need to investigate the [`sqrt`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/sqrt/) function, and maybe also the [`pow`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/) function as well (although that's unnecessary because `b`-squared can be computed as `b*b`).

Note that you will need to convert all of your input values to `float` or `double` before you start the calculation, otherwise you will not get the intended result.

Comment: and remember to change the scanf line, and the printf if we are being picky.

Comment: @Sasquiha: Not necessarily!  We could cast on the way into the formula, and the printf is already `%f`.

Comment: And check for a negative discriminant (imaginary roots) before calling `sqrt()`.

Comment: The guy is having basic problems without getting into casting. And I meant the printf above the scanf.

Answer (score 3):

You need a table to allow you to translate:

a+b -> `a+b`

a-b -> `a-b`

a/b -> `a/b`

ab -> `a*b`

√x -> `sqrt(x)`

x² -> `x*x` (If you want to square something more complicated it might be best to use a temporary variable for the value to be squared, breaking your equation up into pieces.)

Note that if you divide an `int` by an `int` in C you get an int. So better convert those `int`s to `double`s before dividing.

Answer (score 1):

If we are dealing with C++ it would be something *like*

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <cmath>

int main ()

{
//Declare Variables
double x,x1,x2,a,b,c;
cout << "Input values of a, b, and c." ;
cin >>a >>b >>c;
    if ((b * b - 4 * a * c) > 0)
    cout << "x1 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)" &&
    cout << "x2 = (-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)";

    if else ((b * b - 4 * a * c) = 0)
    cout << "x = ((-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)"

    if else ((b * b - 4 * a * c) < 0)
    cout << "x1 = ((-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c) * sqrt (-1)) / (2 * a) &&
    cout << "x2 = ((-b + sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c) * sqrt (-1)) / (2 * a);
return (0);
}
```

Now why do i have this wierd feeling I just did someone's first semester programming class' homework?

Granted its been years and I don't even know if that will compile but you should get the idea.

Comment: This most definitely won't compile!  Also, it doesn't calculate or print a numerical result at any point...

Comment: but the idea is there (using sqrt and doube and input/outputs) ... i have an uneasy feeling basically DOING people homework, but wanted to get him off on the right track...

Comment: haha! not really, this is just a small fragment of the problem I needed to solve a bigger one. Good job and thanks for your help, i just needed to translate the equation to the editor :)

Answer (score 0):

I am really depressed looking the quality of above answers and help, which has been given.

I hope to improve the content of this thread.

One can compile the C file below with the command line `gcc file.c -o file -lm`.

Herewith a possible solution in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int da, db, dc;
    double x, a,b,c;

    //statements
    printf("Enter three integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &da, &db, &dc);

    a = (double)da;
    b = (double)db;
    c = (double)dc;

    //computeforX
    x = (double) ( -b + sqrt(b * b) - 4 * a * c ) / ( 2 * a )  ;

    printf("The value of x is %g \n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you including `<stdlib.h>`? And what are all those casts for?

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for user input. And if you do, always check its return value.

Comment: Your formula is wrong. It should be `sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)`.